# What do きゃるん、きゃるーん、きゅるん、きゅるるん and related words mean?

Tags: meaning, words, nuances, onomatopoeia

In the anime [Saiki K. S2 E10 (image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abr3u.jpg), きゃるーん appears as a sound effect, where I would rather expect じゃーん or the like. Googling various Japanese forums has led me to conclude that the other variants mentioned in the title are similar/variants, but as for the meaning, people seem to conclude that it's merely a character-thing without meaning, or perhaps means something like かわいい. But that doesn't seem to be the case in my screenshot - or is it?

Answer (score 1):

[This is what I found](https://www.wdic.org/w/MOE/%E3%81%8D%E3%82%83%E3%82%8B%E3%80%9C%E3%82%93%E2%98%86):

> きゃる〜ん☆
>
> 辞書：萌色用語の基礎知識　ゲーム・アダルト編 (GADULT)
> 読み：きゃるーん
> 品詞：感動詞
>
> 1996(平成8)年12月発売、カクテルソフト制作の18禁ゲームソフト、きゃんきゃんバニープルミエール2で登場したキャラ "スワティ" の決めゼリフ。
>
> 同社が初めて声を入れた作品で、電源を入れると最初にいきなり椎名へきるの声でこのセリフが入る。当時はまだゲームに音声を入れるのが一般的でなかった時代にそのインパクトは計り知れず、きゃんきゃんバニー=きゃる〜ん☆という図式が出来上がるほどであった。

Summary:

In [Can Can Bunny Premiere 2](https://www.mobygames.com/game-group/can-can-bunny-series), an adult game produced by [Cocktail Soft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_Soft) and released in December 1996, a character called [スワティ](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AF%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3) uses this as her catchphrase. This was the first game with voice produced by that company. When the power was turned on, this line suddenly came out in [Hekiru Shiina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hekiru_Shiina)'s voice. At a time when it was uncommon for games to have recorded voice, the impact was immeasurable.

Comment: But do you really think the mention in Saiki K. is a reference to this? It feels a little niche for that, no?

Comment: @Sam I gave the **etymology** of the term. The work you saw doesn't have to be a direct reference to the origin, but since your question is "what does it mean?" it is definitely related to the origin of the term and either way it _does_ seem to be a niche term, in the work you saw and in its place of origin.

Comment: I vaguely remember this became a meme among otaku 20 years ago or so. It's definitely a 死語 now, but this character looks like a stereotypical *kogyaru* in the 00's, which may explain why such an old word is used here.